# Layers containing TIN surfaces missing from layer manager after translation from DWG to SVF

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

When translating a DWG to SVF, the layers containing TIN surfaces are missing from the layer manager. However the TIN object itself is present in the model and the object properties show the object's layer name. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Can you please share a drawing with me, this is not expected, you can email me the drawing at ---  "forge[dot]help[at]autodesk[dot]com"

Comment: I sent the email with the model. Thank you for taking a look at it.

Comment: Thanks, I can reproduce the behavior, I will keep you posted.